# NWPathMonitor not calling satisfied in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, networking, detection

I'm using `NWPathMonitor`to detect when internet connection is on and off. The method gets called when both states happens, however when the internet connection is on, the called status still is `.unsatisfied`instead of `.satisfied`. Here's the class that I'm using:

```
import Network

protocol NetworkCheckDelegate {
    func statusDidChange(status: NWPath.Status)
}

class NetworkCheck {

    private var monitor = NWPathMonitor()

    private static let _sharedInstance = NetworkCheck()

    var networkCheckDelegate: NetworkCheckDelegate?

    class func sharedInstance() -> NetworkCheck {
        return _sharedInstance
    }

    // Create only one instance of NetworkCheck
    private init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.networkCheckDelegate?.statusDidChange(status: path.status)
            })
        }
        monitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
    }

    func removeMonitoring() {
        monitor.cancel()
    }
}
```

My question is: Why does is the internet connection is called as `.unsatisfied`in both cases

Comment: It may be because you haven't requested a specific network interface type to monitor?  What happens if you ask it to monitor cellular or wifi specifically?

Comment: does the simulares uses WiFi as the default one?

Comment: Are you testing this on the simulator?  I would expect that to work at all. You need to test on a real device.

Comment: @Paulw11 why is it not working when using the simulator? Is there a way to get it working when using the simulator? I have the same behavior, the handler gets called when I turn off/on wifi on my computer, but when i turn it on the status is still .unsatisfied

Comment: No, because the simulator doesn’t have multiple network interfaces (cellular and wifi). It just has a single connection via the host computer. The simulator is not a replacement for a real device when it comes to all testing.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok, thanks. Maybe this could be added as an answer?

Comment: @Gustav I was testing on an actual device, I want to use a simulator because I thought that my device had an issue

Comment: oh, ok. You have this issue while using device and not only using simulator? I've only seen this issue (status still being .unsatisfied when wifi is turned back on) while using simulator

Comment: yes, while using the device

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your explanation about why this doesn't work on the simulator. You should get credit for the answer. I just spend too much time finding out the hard way. For the record, I was on 14.3

Comment: In my case with simulator, when I turn it of it detects it. When i turn it on, it still returns unavailable. If i turn it off again it returns staisfied this time. After that it always returns opposite of the state.

Answer (score 2):

The simulator cannot accurately transfer network changes to the application.

In my experience, it will be the network status of the device you are running Xcode on at launch, and only update itself when you go from having a connection (satisfied) to not (unsatisfied), but not the other way around.

You need to test network on real devices due to this limitation.

Comment: No, simulators works for this -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEJzc81oCk4

Comment: @jose920405 Which part of this video is there ever a simulator being run??

Comment: did you see the video? minute 5:00